# Automatic fold/unfold Y-axis break on mouse over

Tags: highcharts, mouseevent, axis

I need to build a "basic" columns (horizontal or vertical) chart with Y-axis break. I used the sample provided here https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/axisbreak/break-visualized/ to achieve that and the result is fine.
Now I need to unfold the Y-axis on mouse over the columns (to display the chart with Y-axis in its original size).
I added some events to do that :

```
plotOptions: {
 column: {
  point: {
    events: {
      mouseOver: function(){
        const chart = this,
        yAxis = chart.series.yAxis;
        yAxis.update({
          breaks: [],
        });
      },
      mouseOut: function(){
        const chart = this,
        yAxis = chart.series.yAxis;
        yAxis.update({
          breaks: breakarray,
        });
      }
    }
   }
  }
```

Job is done and the result seems OK, you can see it in the jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/wd5nhcqg/

1st point : I would like the // on the Y-axis and the break-signs in the columns disappear when the mouse over the column (and the chart unfold). Then on mouse out event, the breaking signs (// and signs in the columns) need to be drawn again. How to do that ?

2nd point : With my method, event is triggered when mouse is over each columns. I would prefer the event is only triggered on columns impacted by break axis (columns with a break sign), not the others. Is it possible ?

I tried using the events but without success.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the below code. For the first point I have added `brokenAxis.breakArray` to `this.breakArray` and used `setColumnBreaksVisibility` function in mouse events. For the second point I have changed the `mouseOver` function to clear breaks conditionally.

```
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Axis.prototype, 'getLinePath', function(proceed, lineWidth) {
    ...
    (this.breakArray || []).forEach(function(brk) { 
        ...
    });
    ...
});

function pointBreakColumn(e) {
    ...
    if (!point[key]) {
        point.breakKey = key;
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}

function setColumnBreaksVisibility(series, show) {
    series.forEach(function(s) {
        s.points.forEach(function(point) {
            if (point.breakKey) {
                point[point.breakKey][show ? 'show' : 'hide']()
            }
        });
    });
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function() {
                        const point = this,
                            allSeries = point.series.chart.series,
                            yAxis = point.series.yAxis;

                        if (this.breakKey) {
                            setColumnBreaksVisibility(allSeries);
                            yAxis.update({
                                breaks: []
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    mouseOut: function() {
                        const point = this,
                            allSeries = point.series.chart.series,
                            yAxis = point.series.yAxis;

                        if (!point.breakArray) {
                            yAxis.update({
                                breaks: breakarray,
                            });
                            setColumnBreaksVisibility(allSeries, true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tchLvnx8/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#hide

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#show

Comment: Many thanks, it's exactly what I want. I have another question to improve the break axis management : is it possible that Highcharts calculates automatically the breaks values ("from" and "to" values) because sometime, we don't know in advance the gap values and manually set the break is not precise enough.

Comment: Hi @vegaelce, No, it is not possible, but you can create your own functions to generate breaks based on some extremes values.